# passport RESTAPI authentication

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, grouping, passport.js

I am novice to Node passport authentication. I completely write an example of passport authentication as below:

```
var express = require('express');

var passport = require('passport');
var passportLocal = require('passport-local');

/* 
Since express doesn't support sessions by 
default you need following middlewares.
*/
// For storing session ID in browser
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// For rendering credentials from request bodies
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/*
For server side storage of session information.
All these session information is in server memory. 
If the machine app reboot all sessions infromation 
will disapear. The information coming with request
, thanks to cookies, with the session information
stored in the server used in deserializing the users.
Be careful properly handle session information
in server farms, round robbining and load balancing etc.
But it is easy to configure express-session middleware
to use external storage. In this case we use local machine.
*/
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// For sessions. Need before Passport middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    // This is the secret used to sign the session ID cookie.
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'd7n5ihsxx9by8ydt',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Passport need 2 middlewares
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/*
Strategies need to be told how to veryfy username and password
that is inside authorization header that is client is goint to send.
*/
function verifyCredentials(username, password, done) {
    /*
    Use crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen[, digest], callback)
    For the real app.
    */
    if (username === password) {
        /*
        done() first argument is Error
        Second argument 'user' is any object required for your business logic.
        But make it as much as smaller for fast serializing and deserializing.
        */
        done(null, {
            id : 123,
            name: username,
            role: 'Admin',
            catogery : 'Operator'
        });
    } else {
        done(null, null);
    }
};

/*
Now we have to configure passport. Call the local strategy with
single function function(username, password, done) where done is callback
funciton.
*/
passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy(verifyCredentials));

/*
passport.serializeUser serializes the 'user' object.
The callback function done, need a small piece of
'user' object which is required in deserializing.
In following case 'user.id' is saved to session 
req.session.passport.user = {id:'..'}
*/
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

/*
In deserialize function you provide in first argument of 
deserialize function that same key of user object that was 
given to done function in serialize call. So your whole object is
retrieved with help of that key. that key here is id. 
In deSerialize function that key is matched with in 
memory array / database or any data resource.
*/
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    /*
    Query database or cache here! Example

    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
    */
    done(null, {
        id : id,
        name: id,
        role: 'Admin',
        catogery : 'Operator'
    }); 
});

/*
Middleware for API's. 3rd party middlewares are available
to download and install if you want. Middleware is 
nothing but a simple function with the following format.
'next' is callback function which is used to pass the request
to the next middleware inline.
*/
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(403).json( {msg: '403 Forbidden'} ); 
    }
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        /*
        Express doesn't have isAuthenticated for req. 
        But passport add it to req. Also the 'user' object
        added in done() callback is available through req.
        */
        isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated(),
        user : req.user
    });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    //Passport add logout method to request object
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

/*
In this end point, the middleware passport.authenticate('local') is called.
passport.authenticate('local') returns a functon similar to ensureAuthenticated.
*/
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

/*
Second endpoint for API's. The endpoint is authenticated
with a middleware which is between URI and function.
*/
app.get('/api/data', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        {name: 'My'},
        {name: 'Kumara'}
    ]);
});

app.get('/api/data/me', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        {name: 'My'},
        {name: 'Kumara'}
    ]);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on Port : ' + port);
})
```

My question:
I have two URI's:

```
/api/data
/api/data/me
```

I assumed that since I have authenticated `/api/data` it will automatically authenticate `/api/data/me` since `/api/data` part is already authenticated, `/api/data/me` is like a child of `/api/data`. But it's not. Does this mean do I have to authenticate each and every API's?

If not, how can I group set of API's in a single strategy?

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard could be used to match everything under a certain path.  For example:

```
app.get('/api/data/*', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next) {
    next(); // call next matching route
});

app.get('/api/data/me', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
       {name: 'My'},
       {name: 'Kumara'}
    ]);
});
```

This enables the passport middleware for all requests under /api/data/ so that the user will need to authenticate using the passport local strategy. Logic for individual endpoints under /api/data/ can then be implemented without including the passport middleware.

There's more information about express route matching on the user guide. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html